# flipping in Viewflipper if EditText have value "nitesh"

Tags: android, viewflipper

I am using ViewFlipper in my app but i am having an issue. I have a EditText and a button  inside the ViewFlipper. I want that ViewFlipper should flip next background if the value of EditText is "nitesh" and the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View view) {
        EditText textbox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textbox);
        ViewFlipper flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
        if(textbox.getText().equals("nitesh"))
            flipper.startFlipping();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the value of the EditText that is in view at that time and then based on that value figure out what to do.